# Controller not found when deploying a Play application on Heroku

Tags: heroku, playframework, playframework-2.0

I am running a Play application written in Java and running 2.11.1. It works fine locally and I successfully pushed it to Heroku a couple times. Since then, I have added a new controller and updated the routes with a couple of new actions.

It works fine locally but when deploying to Heroku, I get the following error (one for all the actions for this controller):

```
   [error] /tmp/scala_buildpack_build_dir/conf/routes:12: object Dataset is not a member of package controllers
   [error] GET    /data                        controllers.Dataset.list()
```

I am using another controller that has been defined in the same fashion (only before) and it works fine. Extract from routes:

```
   # Models page
   GET     /models                     controllers.PredictionModels.list()

   # Data page
   GET    /data                        controllers.Dataset.list()
```

Is there a known problem on Heroku? Is it because I run Dev locally and Production on Heroku?

Comment: How do you deploy to Heroku? Did you clean project before deploying?

Comment: I have tried three different ways: simply pushing using "git heroku push master", I have also set the SBT_CLEAN variable to true to force a clean and re-pushed and I have deployed to a new app, same issue.

Comment: Adding new controllers to an application should be trivial. Sounds like the `Dataset` controller is really missing package declaration on the top of the class...